# How to use common parameter for Mysql PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have tried to make a search query and my query statement is like the following:

```
<?php
$query= $db->prepare("SELECT
                          p.id, 
                          p.name, 
                          p.surname, 
                          p.phone, 
                          t.title, 
                          j.job, 
                          d.department
                       FROM
                          People p 
                       JOIN
                          Titles t ON p.title_id = t.id
                       JOIN 
                          Departments d ON p.dept_id = d.id
                       JOIN 
                          Jobs j ON p.job_id = j.id
                       WHERE
                          p.name LIKE :v1 OR
                          p.surname LIKE :v2 OR 
                          p.phone LIKE :v3 OR 
                       ORDER BY 
                          d.department, 
                          p.name, 
                          p.surname"
              );

$query->bindValue(":v1", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":v2", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":v3", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
?>
```

`$value` comes from a textbox in which search string is typed. The query works fine.

What I want to learn is why  I have to use 3 parameters for just one value. Why cannot I type the statement like:

```
p.name LIKE :v1 OR
p.surname LIKE :v1 OR 
p.phone LIKE :v1 OR
```

and then bind the parameter once only?

```
$query->bindValue(":v1", $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Have you tried it ? Can you not do it?

Comment: What PHP version you are using?

Comment: Of course I have tried it. I get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'`

Comment: @yourcommonsense PHP version is 5.4.3

Comment: Can you try your code with ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES reversed?

Comment: Yup, just tested it- it works in emulated mode for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/243
Something about stability in memory handling..

I wrote this as an answer because I cant comment yet.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have got my answer

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ there are comments under this article telling that things got changed several times since then.

Answer (score 1):

The doc of [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php) says:

> You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement.